# set java system property during maven 2 compile?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a maven profile and want to set a property which is later on available per System.getProperty(..) in java:

```
<profile>
  <id>local-dev</id>
  <properties>
    <my.comp.my.prop>myValue</my.comp.my.prop>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

I want `System.getProperty("my.comp.my.prop")` to be `"myValue"` but it's `null`..
How do I set it correctly? :)

Thansk!

Comment: Do you really mean 'compile'? Or perhaps the unit tests?

Comment: What do you mean by "later available"? You set a system property, for example, by using `-Dmy.comp.mu.prop=foo` when you execute the app.

Comment: Somewhere in my server side code I want to read the property to do different things when compiled in different compile-profiles.

Comment: You didn't answer bmargulies question: During compile or during the run of the unit tests? Otherwise you have to use a property file which should be located to src/main/resources or src/test/resources.

Comment: not in a test... in the run of the live code I want it. do you have an example of how to use a property file for that?

Comment: I'm not sure what the word "live code" means. Are you deploy/run your project out side maven? e.g. deploy to the application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven cannot set a property which can be accessed by your application from the environment at runtime.

Instead, you can use maven to update a property file in your codebase during build time, which can then be read by your application at runtime. Different values of the property can be set based on the profile, thereby allowing your application to have different values as desired.

Alternately, you can invoke the application setting the desired property in the environment manually (outside maven).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a standard procedure how to build and read such a property file?

Comment: Just for further readers, this is done using the Maven Resources Plugin's filtering capability: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 9):

[properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/set-system-properties-mojo.html) plugin will help you to do exactly what you're looking for:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>my.property.name</name>
                        <value>my.property.value</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This gives me: Unrecognised tag: 'executions'

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this sets properties for the maven lifecycle, put they are not available to java at runtime. I have tried it would no success. Am I not correct?

Comment: @yegor256 If you are still there in SO:  I guess what John B says makes sense. The properties here is for maven lifecycle.
I put a -1 for your answer which I feel is not correct in context of the Q.
I'll upvote it if you can clarify on John's comments.

Comment: @JohnB of course, these properties are only available at Maven build cycle. What is "Java runtime" in this context?) What if your build produces 5 JAR files and 2 WARs. Which Java runtime in particular we will be talking about?)