# How to output text to a file in resource folder Maven

Tags: java, maven, csv

Here is the structure of my maven project:

main and test folders are under src folder, java and resources folders are under main folder, 
in the resources folder, there is a csv file ready for reading.

```
src  
  --main  
    |-- java  
    |-- resources  
           |-- test.csv
test
```

Currently, I am trying to overwrite the test.csv file using supercsv library.

I know that `public CsvMapWriter(Writer writer, CsvPreference preference)` method is helpful on that.

So, I am trying to use OutputStreamWriter, but how to access that file like using:

```
 InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("acacia_implexa.csv"));
 mapReader = new CsvMapReader(reader, CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
```

Comment: You cannot overwrite files in your classpath in Java. It's nothing to do with Maven.

Comment: resources (usually) get zipped up into JAR files along with your classes and are abstracted away from file system files. this is another reason you can only read them as InputStreams using the ClassLoader. even if you could it would be bad practice. suggest you read the initial CSV from the resource and then save the updated version to the user directory or some other logical place.

Answer (score 6):

You **can** output text to a file in the `resources` folder, but the process is a bit tedious.

1. [Tell Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9714018/3041008) to write the location of your `resources` folder into a file
2. Read the location of your `resources` folder in Java
3. Use that location to write your file to

### Notes

- Why bother specifying the location of your `resources` folder file? Isn't it `src/main/resources` always? Well no, if you have a nested module structure like

  ```
  rootModule   
  ├─ childModule1   
  │  └─ src    
  │     └─ main    
  │        └─ resources    
  └─ childModule2 
     └─ ...
  ```

  then the relative path `src/main/resources` resolves to `parentModule/src/main/resources` which does not exist.
- Once you write the file to the `resources` folder, it will not be accessible through `Class.getResource()`. `Class.getResource()` provides you with read access to files located in your classpath. The files located in your `resources` folder are "copied" to your binary output folder (read classpath) **during "compilation"**. In order to access your newly created resource file with the help of `Class.getResource()`, you will have to recompile & restart the application. However, you can still access it by the location you used for writing the file.

### Guide

1. add `RESOURCE_PATH` property to the Maven pom, and tell Maven to compile properties found in resource files
2. add an utility file `src/main/resources/RESOURCE_PATH`, which only contains the `RESOURCE_PATH` property
3. extract the `RESOURCE_PATH` property from the utility file in Java
4. rebuild the project if needed (e.g. if file/folder structure changes)

#### POM

```
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <RESOURCE_PATH>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</RESOURCE_PATH>
    </properties>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${RESOURCE_PATH}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        ....
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

#### Utility file (`src/main/resources/RESOURCE_PATH`)

```
${RESOURCE_PATH}
```

#### Java

```
/**
 * Reads the relative path to the resource directory from the <code>RESOURCE_PATH</code> file located in
 * <code>src/main/resources</code>
 * @return the relative path to the <code>resources</code> in the file system, or
 *         <code>null</code> if there was an error
 */
private static String getResourcePath() {
    try {
        URI resourcePathFile = System.class.getResource("/RESOURCE_PATH").toURI();
        String resourcePath = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(resourcePathFile)).get(0);
        URI rootURI = new File("").toURI();
        URI resourceURI = new File(resourcePath).toURI();
        URI relativeResourceURI = rootURI.relativize(resourceURI);
        return relativeResourceURI.getPath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    File file = new File(getResourcePath() + "/abc.txt");
    // write something to file here
    System.out.println(file.lastModified());
}
```

I hope that works. Maybe you need [maven resources:resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) and do `mvn generate-resources process-resources`

Comment: I know this answer is 4 years old but maybe u can still help me. When i call System.class.getResource("/RESOURCE_PATH") it returns null @mucaho

Answer (score 0):

You can override the file but that would only work in IDE, if it would be executed as part of jar it would fail because it is not a file any more( its file inside file)

Better to externalize file and read/overwrite from that location

If you still would like to read this file and overwrite it then you can do something like

```
Thread.getclassloader().get resource("/");
```

This will give you path up to your target/classes directory you can navigate to resources from here using double dots

Comment: Comminity manager - there is no easyWay to format answer frkm android app