# How could I get the output results in the resources folder?

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea

I have a Java project with structure as following:

[image]

I can read the `hotels.csv` file using the code;

```
  ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("hotels.csv").getFile());
```

I have `results.xml` output file that also needs to be in the same folder as shown in the image. Currently, I do that using the code,

```
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("src/main/resources/result.xml"));
```

How can I do that programmatically by only saying the file name, say, `result.xml` and get the path using the program?

I have seen a post in the forum for the same issue and didn't get any result after following. I configured the `pom.xml` file as following,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Trivago</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${RESOURCE_PATH}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Trivago</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- Use the latest version whenever possible. -->
        <jackson.version>2.4.4</jackson.version>
        <RESOURCE_PATH>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</RESOURCE_PATH>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

An later try to use the method to get the path for the resources folder as suggested,

```
        private static String getResourcePath() {

        try {
            URI resourcePathFile = System.class.getResource("/RESOURCE_PATH").toURI();
            String resourcePath = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(resourcePathFile)).get(0);
//            System.out.println("resourcePath = " + resourcePath);

            URI rootURI = new File("").toURI();
            URI resourceURI = new File(resourcePath).toURI();
            URI relativeResourceURI = rootURI.relativize(resourceURI);
            return relativeResourceURI.getPath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Leter, I intended to use 
`StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(getResourcePath() +"/result.xml"));`

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` while running this line of command `URI resourcePathFile = System.class.getResource("/RESOURCE_PATH").toURI();`

UPDATE: I also run the command `mvn generate-resources process-resources` suggested in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567497/how-to-output-text-to-a-file-in-resource-folder-maven?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You **can not**, and should not, be doing this. The `src/main/resources` directory doesn't exist at runtime -- the resources are mapped into the jar file into the same folder structure as the `.class` files, with the root package in the root of the jar file. There is no `src/main/anything` at runtime.

There are operations that will create a temporary directory if you need one, or you can write to a known location on the hd, though these are both poor solutions. Rather, you should write your output to standard-out and use linux (or dos) pipeline tools to redirect that to a path and file dictated by the user. The next best thing is to pick up the destination file location from an environment variable.