# How to update a file inside the Java Web Application on user action from UI?

Tags: java, file, file-io, resources, classloader

**Context**

I am trying out a simple Java  Dynamic Web Maven Application wherein I ask the user to subscribe to my website by entering his email id in the input field in the UI.

The email id is successfully received in my ManagedBean handler from UI.

So far all is good and happens as expected!

**Problem**

I want to store this email id in a file `"sendReminders.txt"` in my application. This file is stored in the resources folder of my web application helloworld ( a screenshot attached).

[image: snapshot of my sample web app]

But then after going through this post [How to output text to a file in resource folder Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567497/how-to-output-text-to-a-file-in-resource-folder-maven) I realize that we can't directly write to files in the resources folder of the application. But there is a way to do that and am not sure how.

The code below updates the file in the deployment directory of my JBoss server located at `C:\Users\mulshankar13\jboss-eap-7.0\standalone\deployments\helloworld2.war\WEB-INF\classes\sendReminders.txt`

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("sendReminders.txt").getFile());
System.out.println(" did i find the file ? =" + file.exists() + " write = " + file.canWrite() + " read = "+ file.canRead());
printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
printWriter.write(email);
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: As to your actual question: **never, ever update files __inside__ your deployed project. Om a redeploy it will all be removed.** There are several Q/A on stackoverflow about this (not jsf related). And the Q you refer to is about a pre-deployed src folder. Besides all this, your tagging is waaaay off.

Comment: @Kukeltje At times desperation takes the better of rationalism! As it did for me in this Q. I gave it an after thought after your (not so pleasant ;-)) shake up and realized that I can achieve what I want to do through embedded database. Am trying that ...will update that as my answer once I have implemented the same.